# Cannot do SQL Case when bit value = 1 THEN post_date >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large select query and need to enter a where statement when a bit var = 1 (and in most cases they won't so) then we need to make sure we compare the post_date var is NOT within the past 24hours.

What I am trying to do is:

```
case when bit value = 1 THEN post_date >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
```

But for all other records that do not have that bit var set to 1, we get those records.

So here is what I was trying to do:

```
SELECT 
WARNING_EVENTS.id, 
WARNING_EVENTS.message_id, 
WARNING_EVENTS.warning, 
MESSAGE_PREPARED.county
FROM WARNING_EVENTS
INNER JOIN MESSAGE_PREPARED ON WARNING_EVENTS.message_id = MESSAGE_PREPARED.message_id

WHERE MESSAGE_PREPARED.county IS NOT NULL
AND MESSAGE_PREPARED.county <> ''
AND ACCOUNTS.noaa = 1
AND ACCOUNTS.active = 1
AND MESSAGE_PREPARED.active = 1
AND 
CASE repeat_prevention
         WHEN 1 THEN MESSAGE_PREPARED.last_post
```

And of course this was not working. I can do it with the code web server but know the best way to do it is in the query.

In the `message_prepared` table there are some record that we set a bit flag to 1 to denote that we should only include them if the `post_date` is outside of 24hrs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Whats the rest of the logic? You probably just want a combination of `AND` & `OR` - but unless you show us the logic we can't help. Sample data and desired results would also help clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Oh its in your title... you need to make sure the question is stand alone as people expect to be able to read through the question itself and understand your problem.

Comment: Please update your code to include the rest of the `CASE` to allow us to better assist you here.  Even from the title the CASE appears to be incomplete

Comment: So basically in the message_prepared table there are some record that we set a bit flag to 1 to denote that we should only include them if the post_date is outside of 24hrs.

Comment: Any other records that have that bit flag set to 0 the date doesn't matter. Does that make sense?

Comment: I made one edit for you, please add any additional clarity you can here by editing your question with more details (a small sample data set may assist our understanding here)

Comment: Sorry here is the case statement:

Comment: CASE repeat_prevention
             WHEN 1 THEN MESSAGE_PREPARED.last_post >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `CASE` *expression* for this, just simple AND/OR logic e.g.

```
AND (
    repeat_prevention = 0
    OR MESSAGE_PREPARED.last_post >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
)
```

Note: `CASE` is an expression i.e. it allows you to conditionally return a value. Its not a statement which would allow you to conditionally add a further statement.